# eBPF and global variables support in Debian 5.15 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi4, ebpf, bpf

I am running Raspbin OS which is essentially Debiain distribution on Raspberry Pi Model 4B. The linux kernel version is 5.15.80 and I customized the kernel by setting flags for eBPF support. I have written an eBPF program which extracts basic packet info like src and dest IP and ports and TCP checksum.
I want to compute packet switching delay per packet for which I have gotten the timestamps for arrival of packet on ingress interface (wlan0 of Pi) and departure on egress interface (eth0 of pi). To be able to compute the delta in the kernel component of my eBPF program, I was trying to maintain pkt checksum record with arrival and departure and once the delta is computed, get rid of this checksum record.
Somehow this record which was a global variable (struct) is not liked by eBPF. Through various question-answers I found in once place that support for global variables in Linux is present from version 5.2? Support for static variables is still not present.
Any idea if I might be missing anything? When I compile the program having global variable it results in invalid opcode error and with a warning that says globals and statics are not supported.

Explained above. Read through Stackoverflow forums to find that from kernel 5.2, eBPF has support for global variables.

I have two functions I am attaching kprobes to; and from those two functions, I am trying to manipulate this structure like this:

```
From foo1():
  ts_arrival = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
  p = kzalloc(sizeof(struct packet_record_t), GFP_KERNEL);
  p->checksum = csum; p->ts_arr = ts_arrival;

From foo2():
  ts_departure = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
  if (p->checksum == csum) {
    p->ts_dep = ts_departure;
    delta = p->ts_dep - p->ts_arr;
  }
```

Chakrapani Chitnis
Apr 11 at 21:34
The error I get from bpf verifier says this:

`bpf: Failed to load program: Invalid argument unknown opcode 00 processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0 HINT: The 'unknown opcode' can happen if you reference a global or static variable, or data in read-only section. For example, 'char *p = "hello"' will result in p referencing a read-only section, and 'char p[] = "hello"' will have "hello" stored on the stack.`

Comment: Correct, global variables/data support exists but not in older versions. Can you clarify the "Somehow this record which was a global variable (struct) is not liked by eBPF" do you have a specific error message. Or did you expect something to happen and something else happend?

Comment: Thanks for responding Dylan. The kernel component record structure definition I have is as follows:

struct packet_record_t {
  __u16 checksum;
  __u64 ts_arr, ts_dep;
};
struct packet_record_t *p = NULL;

Comment: I have two functions I am attaching kprobes to; and from those two functions, I am trying to manipulate this structure like this:

From foo1():

ts_arrival = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
      p = kzalloc(sizeof(struct packet_record_t), GFP_KERNEL);
      p->checksum = csum;
      p->ts_arr = ts_arrival;

From foo2():

ts_departure = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
      if (p->checksum == csum) {
        p->ts_dep = ts_departure;
        delta = p->ts_dep - p->ts_arr;
      }

Comment: The error I get from bpf verifier says this:

bpf: Failed to load program: Invalid argument
unknown opcode 00
processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

HINT: The 'unknown opcode' can happen if you reference a global or static variable, or data in read-only section. For example, 'char *p = "hello"' will result in p referencing a read-only section, and 'char p[] = "hello"' will have "hello" stored on the stack.

Comment: << Correct, global variables/data support exists but not in older versions. >> Could you please tell me which version has a support for this?

Currently on my Raspberry Pi 4B, I have this: (I have set some eBPF support flags in kernel config so it's a customized kernel per se but version info is as follows):

admin@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.89-v8-for-eBPF+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 24 22:43:13 PST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I moved on to kernel 6.1 and still can't seem to have support that I am looking for, for the use-case described above.

Comment: Please add the above information to your post and format it.

Comment: I suspect you're having this error not because of global variables, but because you are trying to call `kzalloc` from your BPF program. That is not supported.